# How to create a custom information windows google map flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm converting my application to application use Flutter. At the google map plugin, I don't know to create custom information windows same image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Custom Marker for Google map in Flutter
https://github.com/vancuong0429/everyday/blob/master/lib/screens/main/maps_screen.dart